# How to check if an input is already in a list - Batch

Tags: windows, list, batch-file

Doing this in Windows Batch. I have a list of names and asking user to enter their name.
I want to check if that name already exists in the list, if so then it goes straight to a `goto` otherwise it will add the name to the list.

```
@echo off
set "list=Bob,Steve,Harry"

set /p "name=What is your name?"
for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%i in ("%list%") do (
    if %%i=="%name%" (
        goto nameInList
    )
)
set "list=%list%,%name%"

:nameInList
... some code here ...
```

I've had a look around and only found how to compare if a string is in a file which is where I got and edited `for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%i in (%list%) do` but it still trying to find the file "list".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Easiest way is to use `find.exe` or the more flexible `findstr.exe`.

Comment: I will often make sure my list is fully delimited, including leading and trailing delimiters.  Then I would simply `echo %list%|find /i ",%teststring%,"` (using comma as the delimiter).  This keeps "Rob" from matching "Robert".  Could also `echo ,%list%,|find /i ",%teststring%,"`

Comment: I think for your code you can possibly just remove the double quotes around `%list%` in your for statement.  Or maybe try `for /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims=, "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by updating list. If you want to permanently update the list in the batch file itself you need to be clear on that so I can update the answer. For now I assume you just want to temporarily update the list variable:

```
@echo off
set "list=Bob,Steve,Harry"
set /p name=Enter your name:
echo %list% |findstr /i "\<%name%\>" >nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto add
echo %name% already in list
goto :eof
:add
set "list=%list%,%name%"
echo %list%
```

You could however also add all the names to a separate file. For instance:

**names.txt**

```
Bob
Steve
Harry
```

Then the batch file:

```
@echo off
set /p "name=Enter your name: "
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type names.txt ^| findstr /i "\<%name%\>"') do if /i "%%~i"=="%name%" (
   echo %name% already in list && goto :eof
)
:add
echo %name%>>names.txt
echo %name% added to names.txt && set name=
```

This will test each value in the list of names inside of `names.txt` and if no match is found, it will append the name to the file.

Comment: you should better use `echo ,%list%,|findstr /i ",%name%,"` or `echo %list%|findstr /i "\<%name%\>"`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) to find out whether an item is already contained in a list, like this:

```cmd
set "list=Bob,Steve,Harry"
set /p "name=What is your name?"

rem // Augment list with surrounding commas:
set "test=,%list%,"
rem // Try to remove item (name) from augmented list:
call set "test=%%test:,%name%,=,%%"

rem // Compare result with augmented list:
if not ",%list%,"=="%test%" (
    echo Name is already in list!
) else (
    if defined list (set "list=%list%,%name%") else (set "list=%name%")
    echo Name has been added to list.
)
```